# Bad source address when trying to configure UFW via ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, ufw

I'm new to Ansible. I'm trying to write a playbook to configure UFW. My task reads as such:

```
 - name: Allow SSH in UFW
    ufw:
      rule: allow
      port: 22
      proto: tcp
      from_ip:
        - "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - 192.168.0.0/24
      - 10.200.3.0/24
      - 10.200.2.0/24
```

The result that I get back when running the playbook is:

```
failed: [192.168.255.20] (item=192.168.0.0/24) => {"changed": false, "item": "192.168.0.0/24", "msg": "ERROR: Bad source address\n"}
failed: [192.168.255.20] (item=10.200.3.0/24) => {"changed": false, "item": "10.200.3.0/24", "msg": "ERROR: Bad source address\n"}
failed: [192.168.255.20] (item=10.200.2.0/24) => {"changed": false, "item": "10.200.2.0/24", "msg": "ERROR: Bad source address\n"}
```

I can't find anything in the Ansible UFW documentation, or in UFW itself, that would stop this from working. If I remove the 'with_items' loop and enter each IP subnet separately they all work, but that could make for some really long playbooks down the road. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

The documentation I was working from is here:   https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ufw_module.html?highlight=ufw

Edit: Including text from running in verbose mode:

```
failed: [192.168.255.20] (item=10.200.2.0/24) => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "app": null,
            "comment": null,
            "default": null,
            "delete": false,
            "direction": null,
            "from_ip": "['10.200.2.0/24']",
            "from_port": null,
            "insert": null,
            "interface": null,
            "log": false,
            "logging": null,
            "port": 22,
            "proto": "tcp",
            "route": false,
            "rule": "allow",
            "state": null,
            "to_ip": "any",
            "to_port": "22"
        }
    },
    "item": "10.200.2.0/24",
    "msg": "ERROR: Bad source address\n"
```

Comment: firstly, fix the indention. secondly, run ansible with high [verbosity](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-v) and use a [deubgger](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html)

Comment: Adding debugger: on_failed ended with  [WARNING]: Ignoring invalid attribute: debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are passing a list/array to `from_ip`, when it is expecting a string. Try this instead:

```
  - name: Allow SSH in UFW
    ufw:
      rule: allow
      port: 22
      proto: tcp
      from_ip: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - 192.168.0.0/24
      - 10.200.3.0/24
      - 10.200.2.0/24
```